# How to convert rows to column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a dynamic table with distinct values under `ColumnName` in below format and I'm not sure how to convert these rows to columns. Can anyone help?

```
ColumnName      ColumnValue
AccountNumber   123456
AccountBalance  250
AccountState    TX
AccountCity     Houston
```

Target State

```
AccountNumber   AccountBalance  AccountState    AccountCity
123456          250             TX              Houston
```

Comment: Are there only 4 column names?

Comment: Values under ColumnName are distinct and not limited to 4

Comment: This is why dynamic tables or entity-attribute-value tables suck.  They break first normal form and are really hard to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dynamic crosstab](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
    ColumnName  VARCHAR(20),
    ColumnValue VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('AccountNumber', '123456'),
('AccountBalance', '250'),
('AccountState', 'TX'),
('AccountCity', 'Houston');

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT' + CHAR(10);

SELECT @sql = @sql + 
'   MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = ' +QUOTENAME(ColumnName, '''') + ' THEN ColumnValue END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) + ',' + CHAR(10)
FROM tbl;
SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, LEN(@sql) - 1);

SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(10)
+ 'FROM tbl'

PRINT @sql;
EXEC(@sql);
    
DROP TABLE tbl;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/666262)</kbd>

Comment: is it possible to add where condition to select specific rows from a different column ID ?

Comment: I could add where conditions , thanks above solution worked.